# primefaces datatable filtered text lost after Page redirect

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Using `JSF 2` with `Primefaces 4.0`

I filter the Datatable and  navigate from Page1 to Page2.
From Page 2 I navigate back to Page 1, then filtered Text is lost.

The `Managedbean` for Page1 is `Sessionscoped`.

```
<p:dataTable id="customers" var="customer"
    value="#{customerListHandler.customers}"
    selection="#{customerListHandler.selectedCustomer}"
    selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{customer.id}"
    binding="#{customerListHandler.dtCostomers}"
    widgetVar="myTable" >
```

any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: The reason is that you do not store the actual filtering. As far as I know this is just possible using some hacks: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9158. Not a real answer though. Sorry.